# How can I make dry coconut from fresh coconut meat?

Tags: coconut

For my recipe I need dry coconut, but I have only fresh coconut meat in my kitchen. Is there any easy option to convert it into dry coconut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fresh coconut meat is approximately 47% water ([Basic Report of Raw Coconut Meat](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/3656?manu=&fgcd=&ds=) from the USDA National Nutrient Database. I would imagine you could grate fresh coconut meat and spread it on a cookie sheet to dry in an oven. I'd keep it on the lowest setting possible - no more than 150° F (65° C), otherwise it may turn out to taste more toasted. Stir it a number of times to evenly dry.

Since I've never done it, I have no idea how long it would take but I think not more than a day. Hopefully, someone else may have tried it already. Are you sure freshly grated coconut couldn't be substituted?

Answer (score 0):

There is a coconut meat cutter tool. It cuts it in to sting. then dry. But I have never seen one in America. That is the easy way. But were I live we grow our own coconuts.

Comment: I wonder if it's the same tool that used to make long strands of green mango for the Thai/Vietnamese green mango salad? Green mango is quite hard (though not as hard as coconut meat). Makes long evenly thin strands. If so, they can be purchased for a few dollars at Asian grocery shops. The place I frequently shop at carries them

Comment: They are to circles like ring's whit a handle between them. You can sharpen both sides of each circle blade  Cut coconut in 1/2. Take tool by handle. Cut meat out in long round strings of coconut. These are fresh coconuts from our place or gave to us by neighbors. So some softer than what you buy in the store. The meat can then be hung or laid out to dry. Looks like white shoe laces when done. They come in different sizes up to 1/4 inch. With 2 rings you have 4 cutting edges. Both sides are sharpened. So one dull just turn to next one.